# Installing VB6 - error unable to create a DCOM user account

Tags: vb6

When I try to Install Visual Basic 6 (aka Visual Studio 6) on Windows 10 it has this error:

> Setup Error
>
> Setup was unable to create a DCOM user account in order to register ”
>   ..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Common\Tools\VS-Ent98\Vanalyzr\valec.exe”

Is there a workaround for this?

---

Note: I did try running as admin; e.g., running the install from an elevated command window or right-click on installer and select "run as admin". We had tried that in this instance but it had no effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This problem was described in a Microsoft article which now appears to be defunct:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257413

The contents of that page were:

> **Re-install Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Edition without Visual Studio
>   Analyzer:**
>
> 1. Use the Custom setup, on the Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Custom page, click Enterprise Tools, and then click Change Option.
> 2. On the Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Enterprise Tools page, under Options, make sure the Visual Studio Analyzer check box is not
>      selected.
> 3. Click to select all the other Visual Studio components that you want to install, and then click OK.
> 4. Click Continue, and then follow the instructions that appear.
>
> **To install Visual Studio Analyzer:**
>
> 1. In Control Panel, double-click Add/Remove Programs, and then click Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Edition.
> 2. Click Change/Remove.
> 3. In Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Setup, click Add/Remove.
> 4. On the Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Maintenance page, click Enterprise Tools, and then click Change Option.
> 5. On the Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Enterprise Tools page, under Options, click Visual Studio Analyzer, and then click OK.
> 6. On the Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Maintenance page, click Continue, and then follow the instructions that appear.
>
> When you receive the error message that is described in the "Symptoms"
>   section, continue with the Visual Studio Setup Wizard. Setup reports a
>   failure.
>
> **To create a local account, which Visual Studio Analyzer will run as:**
>
> 1. On the computer that is running Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 6.0, create a local user. For information about how to create a local user, see Windows 2000 Help.
> 2. Run Distributed COM Configuration (dcomcnfg.exe).
> 3. On the Applications tab, click MSVSA Local Event Concentrator Class, and then click Properties.
> 4. On the Identity tab, set This User to match the user and password you created in step 1 of this procedure.

Similar material was also available here:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f84a9ef0-bee3-4dcf-8045-3b8c56f22180/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-dcom-user?forum=vclanguage
- http://vbcity.com/forums/t/72710.aspx

but all important details are reproduced in this answer.